# How do I edit multiple AD records at once without double-clicking-editing-closing over and over?

Tags: active-directory

I don't know that much about Active Directory on windows 2008, but I'd like to set the Phone Numbers for all the people in my company and I have access to our Active Directory server.

The only way I can figure out now is to open up each user's node individually and enter the phone number.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 7):

If you're setting the phone numbers to the same value (like the main corporate number) then the phone number field is a field that supports mult-edit mode. You can simply shift-select or ctrl-select all of the users at once, right click and select properties, and add the phone number to the phone number field.

Answer (score 4):

Scripting!

I recommend Powershell or VBScript, but most scripting languages can be used.

Answer (score 2):

[Scripting for active directory](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd793613). [This one in particular might be of use](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Update-AD-Users-in-Bulk-ca0068f1).

Answer (score 1):

also besides scripting you can use dsquery and dset commands.

Comment: Which you would likely put into a script anyway.